# OpenAPI. Invalid request example with Generic

Tags: java, openapi, springdoc

I get invalide request example and schema if user Generic, but i get valid response type.

***How can I get a correct view?***

```
@RestController
public abstract class BaseController<D extends BaseObject> {

    @PostMapping
    @Operation(summary = "create")
    public ResponseEntity<D> create(@RequestBody Wrapper<D> payload) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(payload.getPayload());
    }
}
```

```
@RestController
@Tag(name = "example")
public class FirstController extends BaseController<CustomerDto> {

}
```

ps. Invalide request example is object with fields only from parent class/interface - BaseObject

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use v1.4.0, where the support for wrapper types on request has been improved.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks! due to the fact that the version is very new, I missed it.